# Word for someone who is "pretentious", but without negative connotation?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, connotation, diction

Pretentious is defined as "attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed." What if someone does impress others because they actually do have a greater importance, talent, culture, etc.? What would be a good word to describe such a person?

Comment: Someone who impresses is usually referred to as _impressive_.

Comment: You could use "important", "talented", "cultured", etc.

Comment: Won't *remarkable* do?

Comment: If you don't mind sounding a bit old-timey, then _awesome_ works quite well in many cases. It is outdated in this sense, though.

Comment: You could say "genuinely talented/cultured/etc." if you want to explicitly negate any notion of pretense. "He's not pretentious; he genuinely loves 18th century French poetry."

Comment: Informally, "badass" is not inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [notable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/notable)  conveys the idea:

> - worthy of notice; remarkable; outstanding:
> - prominent, important, or distinguished; eminent: notable artists.

Answer (score -1):

If said person is very young we can call them a **prodigy**

> (pl. prodigies) [often with modifier] a young person with exceptional qualities or abilities: a Russian pianist who was a child prodigy in his day.

Older people, i.e. not children, might be refered to as a **virtuoso**

> 1. a person highly skilled in music or another artistic pursuit: a celebrated clarinet virtuoso | [as modifier] virtuoso guitar playing.
> 2. a person with a special knowledge of or interest in works of art or curios.

Other words like **expert**, **hot shot**, or **master** can be used too for specific skills.